# I have an Arduino Rs485 network, and am trying to add a in Raspberry Pi. The Pi is able to send messages to the Arduino's, but is unable to receive

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, rs485

My network consists of multiple Arduino's connected to the [Max485](https://hobbycomponents.com/wired-wireless/663-max485-rs485-transceiver-module). These Arduino's can talk perfectly between each other.

I am currently attempting to wire a Raspberry Pi into the network. I have been following [this tutorial](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/rs485-serial-communication-between-arduino-and-raspberry-pi).

I have enabled the UART pins, and disabled shell over serial.

For testing, I have [wired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUfhD.png) TX(GPIO 14/pin 8) to DI on the MAX485, RX(GPIO 15/pin 10) to RO, GPIO 4 (pin 7) to DE & RE. It is also powering both MAX485 chips, and both chips are grounded to it.
On the arduino side, I am currently using a [Mega](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9ofO.png). It has TX3 to DI, RX3 to RO, and pin 2 to DE/RE. These two devices are the only ones on this network.

Raspi Python:

```
import time
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#sets pin 7 on the GPIO as DE/RE
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)

rs = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0', timeout=5, baudrate=9600)
data = bytearray()
msgIn = bytearray()
addr = 1

# Splits each byte into two, then unfold each half-byte to make a full byte. 
# The slave will take this data, and fold it back to readable form
# This is to ensure anything being read by the slave is actual data, not noise.
def foldOpen(where, what):
    hb = what >> 4
    where.append((hb << 4) | (hb ^ 0x0F))
    lb = what & 0x0F
    where.append((lb << 4) | (lb ^ 0x0F))

# Unfolds the folded data
def unFold():
    sByte, cByte = False, 0
    timeout = time.perf_counter()

    while((time.perf_counter() - timeout) < 1):
        inByte = rs.read()
        if((inByte >> 4) != ((inByte & 0x0F) ^ 0x0F)):
            return 0

        inByte >>= 4

        if(sByte):
            cByte <<= 4
            cByte |= inByte
            return cByte
        else:
            cByte = inByte
            sByte = True
            timeout = time.perf_counter()
    return 0

# add's each piece of data into the crc
def AddCrc(crc, n):
    for i in range(0, 8):
        mix = (n ^ crc) & 0x01
        crc >>= 1
        if(mix):
            crc ^= 0x8C
        n >>= 1
    return crc & 0xFF

#Receives a start bit, then address, then data length, then data, and finally crc. 
#If everything is formatted correctly, the right amound of data is passed and crc correct
#it will return true
def recvMsg(msg):
    msgState = crc = msgL = 0
    timeout = time.perf_counter()

    while(msgState <= 4):
        if(rs.in_waiting > 0):
            if(msgState < 1):
                inByte = rs.read()
                sleep(1)
            else:
                inByte = unFold()

            if(msgState == 4):
                for x in msg:
                    crc = AddCrc(crc, x)
                if(crc == inByte):
                    return 1
            elif(msgState == 3):
                msg.append = inByte
                if(len(msg) == msgL):
                    msgState = 4
            elif(msgState == 2):
                msgL = inByte
                msgState = 3
            elif(msgState == 1):
                if(inByte == addr):
                    msgState = 2
                else:
                    msgState = 5
            elif(msgState == 0):
                print('Start bit is ')
                print(inByte)
                if(inByte == 2):
                    print('accepted')
                    msgState = 1
        if((time.perf_counter() - timeout) >= 5):
            msgState = 5

#Sends a message, starting with start bit (2), addr, msg length, data, and crc
def sendMsg(where, size, what):
    GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
    msg = bytearray()
    crc = 0

    msg.append(2)
    foldOpen(msg, where)
    foldOpen(msg, size)
    for x in what:
        foldOpen(msg, x)
    for x in what:
        crc = AddCrc(crc, x)
    foldOpen(msg, crc)
    rs.write(msg)
    rs.flush()
    GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)

#creating random data to send to slave for testing
data = bytearray()
info = ord('A')
info2 = 45
data.append(info)
data.append(info2)

sendMsg(2, len(data), data)
#reads 1 byte, just so I know I made a connection
timer = time.perf_counter()
while((time.perf_counter() - timer) < 10):
    if(rs.in_waiting):
        inByte = rs.read(1)
        print(inByte)
```

Arduino Code:

```
#include <RS485_Comm.h>
byte enablePin = 2;
byte check = 0;
size_t rsWrite (const byte what) {
  Serial3.write (what);
  Serial3.flush();
}
bool rsAvailable () {
  return Serial3.available ();
}
int rsRead () {
  return Serial3.read ();
}
RS485 myChannel (rsWrite, rsAvailable, rsRead, 20, 2, 2, 1);
//name(Write CB, AvailableCB, ReadCB, buffer, Epin, Addr, Debug)
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial3.begin(9600);
  myChannel.begin();
  Serial.print("A-OK");
}

void loop() {
  if (myChannel.recvMsg()) {
    if (myChannel.getMsg()[0] == 'A') {
      Serial.print("A-OK");
      byte msgOut[] = "A";
      myChannel.sendMsg(msgOut, sizeof(msgOut), 1);
    }
  }

}
```

Again, I can send messages from the Raspi to the Arduino's. The same Arduino, wired in the same configuration, can talk back and forth with other Arduino's on the network.

I just can't get any info from an Arduino to the raspberry pi. rs.read(1) returns nothing, or some random noise. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is your setting at `/boot/cmdline.txt` on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Arduino code still python???

Comment: Whoops, just fixed that.

Comment: and @hcheung its "console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=ea7d04d6-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
"

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question it looks like you are feeding the [GPIO](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#gpio) pins on you RPi with 5V logic.

That might be OK for a quick test but in the long run, something will probably be damaged. You are better off using 3.3V as the supply voltage for the MAX485 if your converter supports it (some of these boards work only with 5V and others seem to be dual voltage).

What seems to be wrong is the UART RX on your RPi, maybe you should verify it's still good. You can follow these steps:

1)Remove all wires on your RPi 40 pin connector.

2)Short RX to TX on the RPi's UART (pins 8 shorted with pin 10).

3)Run minicom: `sudo minicom -D /dev/serial0`

4)Type anything on the screen. If you can see what you are typing it means your UART is working.

5)Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>E</kbd> to activate echo. Type something else on the screen and now you should see each keystroke appear twice.

6)Hit  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> to quit minicom.

There are many tutorials with more details if you need to troubleshoot your UART further. See, for instance, [here](https://amitasinghchauhan.medium.com/serial-port-debugging-101-loopback-test-4a7e40da9055).

If these UART tests are successful you can proceed to connect the RPi to the Arduino and run minicom again, this time you can choose the baud rate with:

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/serial0 -b 9600
```

Then switch on your Arduino to see if you receive.

If you do but your Python code still reports nothing you can be sure the problem is in there (your code looks fine if a bit overly complicated for such a simple task).